# LWJGL keyboard and mouse detect press

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have the following code:

```
private int getKeyboardKeyPressed() {
    while (Keyboard.next()) {
        if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
            int key = Keyboard.getEventKey();
            if (key == Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)
                return -1;

            return key;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private int getMouseKeyPressed() {
    return Mouse.getEventButton();
}
```

I use a swing button to let the user input keypresses (press the button, then press the desired key).

This gives me two problems: first mouse is always returned as 0, however documentation says it should return -1 if nothing was pressed.
I figured this could be because of swing's button press, perhaps, but setting up a new thread which does a sleep at first doesn't work either, neither does plain discarding the first press(es) work.

Second, the keyboard detection does not seem to work at all. It does not detect any presses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently LWJGL needs to have the Display active and cannot catch keys through an active Swing window.

Comment: This is interesting. Would you mind posting either a more formal description of why LWJGL needs to have the Display active, or documentation for where you found this information?

Comment: This was really a long time ago, so this is all that I can recall. I had a popup window for settings and caught the keys/mouse etc. and determined which key was pressed (Press button to set "Action" -> then press a key). LibGDX didn't caught the keys/events, because the popup window had focus. I eventually solved it, with the popup intact, but can't quite recall how. I think if the LWJGL window is not minimized, it might be sufficient for it to be active.

Comment: Okay thank you for trying to recall! Sorry, I didn't notice the post date was so long ago.